# Problem with linking OpenCV to Webots(Ubuntu)

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, linker, pkg-config, webots

I've just started using Webots and I want to include OpenCV for a project. I read that in order to do this, I should modify the makefile of my controller. So, I made a simple controller in which the robot goes forward and it is just fine. I opened then the makefile and I added the first two lines:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro1cb.png)

I have installed OpenCV 3.2 on my system and I confirm it with:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGMG2.png)

Building my controller I see the following:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URsVN.png)

I also tried the

`#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"`

but it said

> fatal error: opencv2/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory

Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you check by the command ```pkg-config --modversion opencv```? To be sure ur opencv exist correctly?

Comment: I've done it. It says 3.2.0

Comment: try this? <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

Comment: I've tried it, it says the same error: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp : No such file or directory. I think something happens with pkg-config in the makefile but I don't understand why. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find here an example of Webots controller using OpenCV:
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/tree/master/projects/samples/howto/vision/controllers/vision

Comment: Haven't solved it yet, but it seems very helpful. Thanks!